# Small folding loft/attic ladder

Tags: attic, ladder

I'm wanting to install a loft ladder. I would prefer one of those nice folding wooden ladders, however upon researching the various types, it seems that these are quite a bit longer than my current loft hatch.

My current opening is approx 760x575mm, whereas the folding wooden ladder requirements are hatches that are over 1 metre in length!

I understand this is due to the whole first length of ladder being stowed on the hatch door itself, rather than the ladder going into the loft itself.

My question is... Are there any alternative wooden folding loft ladders available that would fit onto a standard size hatch door?

Comment: It's also due to code requirements on access opening size, IIRC.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Something silly like that would make sense

Comment: With such a small opening maybe you should not have a ladder attached to and thus obstructing the opening?  Buy a suitable ladder that you can use to climb up and then move it out of the way so you can get objects up and down.   Probably what you're doing already?

Comment: This is a shopping recommendation question. It was answered Feb 14th and already in July 2022 (just 5 months later) there is a (now deleted) "answer" stating that the recommended product is no longer available. This is _exactly_ why shopping questions are off-topic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting this to inches, your hole is about 22x30. That's smaller than most 22x54 models to be sure, but they do make "narrow door" models. The catch there is that the ladder is an extension ladder that sits almost vertically (while the longer doors have a horizontal rest), so you'll need ample vertical clearance to install one.

Werner, for instance, makes [this compact opening ladder](https://www.wernerco.com/us/products/attic-ladders/AASeries/AA1510B), which is 18x24 inches (457mm by 609mm)

[image: Compact attic ladder]

Comment: Yeah, this is the type of loft ladder I'm used to. I was just wondering if you could get a short door alternative of the door-mounted wooden version. Looks like there isn't :-(

Comment: @physicsboy I don't think you'll find one smaller than this one.

Comment: Wonder how she gets that big tub up there?

Comment: @crip659 The anticipation is killing me!